# is using @Component compulsory for using @Autowired using <context:component-scan base-package="org.controller"/>

Tags: java, spring

i want to use @Autowired annotation along with 
 i want to know whether @Component should be used compulsorily along with it or will it work without @Component

Comment: `@Component` tells spring which `Class(Bean)` to  inject ,and `@Autowired` tells where to inject ,so they are interrelated and no you can't use `@Autowired` if you are not using `@Component` or its subisidaries (`@Controller ,@Repository,@Service`)

Comment: but  i am using <context:component-scan base-package=“org.controller”/> as well as i will configure the beans in the xml itself like <bean id="student" class="com.spring.Student"/> this will tell spring which is the bean and then Autowired will tell where to inject that bean ,now is Component compulsory?

Comment: Nopes then its not ,xml will do the injection of bean part :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `@Autowired` to inject any Spring bean, you need to declare/create them (if not already created by Spring itself) using one of the following solutions:

- `@ComponentScan` on a `@Configuration` class (or its XML equivalent `<context:component-scan/>`) combined with one of `@Component,`@Repository`,`@Service`,`
  @Controller`,`@RestController`,`@ControllerAdvice`, and`@Configuration` stereotypes
- declare beans using XML: `<bean class="..." [...]/>`
- declare beans using Java configuration in a `@Configuration` class (`@Bean`): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Once you have declared some beans, you will be able to inject them using `@Autowired` annotation. Also see http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/.